# executing "commands" using selenium-webdriver in node javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, webdriver

I'm interested in executing a number of the advanced "Commands" via the javascript API 
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/command.js

If I start with the base code:

```
var browser = new webdriver
        .Builder()
        .usingServer(server.address())
        .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs())
        .build();
```

every form of "likely" syntax I've tried to execute has failed.  for example:

```
// does not work
console.log(webdriver.Command('getWindowSize'))
// does not work
console.log(browser.Command('getWindowSize'))
```

Does anyone know how to execute "get window size", or "set window size" in selenium javascript webdriver?

Comment: I haven't used the Command stuff, but we have used the ExecuteScript function to execute JavaScript. If I recall, it returns whatever the javascript would normally return, so just excecute a javascript function that returns the window size (I think you might have to do width an height separately or get them separately and return them as an object with 2 values or something.)

Comment: Thanks Pete. `console.log(browser.ExecuteScript('window.height'));` in that context doesn't seem to work. Nor does  `console.log(browser.executor_.execute('window.height'));`  you have any samples ?

Comment: Alex, I've had so many issues, similar to that which you're encountering.  Selenium-webdriver in Node.js is a *mess*.  The whole promises system seems to sort of make sense, but I've yet to find solid real-life examples (beyond simple "hello world" stuff) of how to use it.  I've been trying for the last day to simply get the visible text of an element... (sigh)  I think I'm going to bail on selenium-webdriver, and use http://www.webdriver.io/ instead.  Looks promising, and appears to use the already-familiar chaining syntax to approximate synchrony.

Answer (score 28):

You are probably looking for `driver.executeScript`.

Example:

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
   build();

driver.executeScript('return 2').then(function(return_value) {
    console.log('returned ', return_value)
});
```

This will log 2 to the console.

I also tested this with:

```
driver.get('http://underscorejs.org/');

driver.executeScript('return _').then(function(return_value) {
    console.log('returned ', return_value)
});
```

... which correctly lists all the methods defined on _, so it appears to work.

Comment: Took me a bit longer than usual to find the docs http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/chrome_exports_Driver.html

Answer (score 0):

In my npm package there's a file `node_modules/selenium-webdriver/test/execute_script_test.js` with a great many examples using `driver.executeScript` (at the very end of the file they define `execute` as an alias for `executeScript`).

Comment: While linking to external resources is fine, an answer should be self-contained, and the external resource shouldn't be *strictly* necessary, but rather additional content (actually, this answer doesn't even contain said link, but merely mentions "my npm package").

Comment: It was not my intention to answer the question.  I felt this had already been done.  I intended to point out a useful, supplementary resource which users of selenium-webdriver would already have in the npm module they installed.

Comment: I see now that I could have, probably should have, added this info as a comment rather than an answer

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/test/execute_script_test.js

Answer (score 0):

You need driver.executeScript(). You can either pass a function or a string.

```
const _scraper = () => {
  return document.title;
}

const getPageTitle = async (url) => {
  await driver.get(url);
  const pageTitle = await driver.executeScript(_scraper);
  console.log(pageTitle);
}
```

You can also pass argument to the function.

```
const _scraper1 = (arg) => {
  return document.getElementsByTagName(arg);
}

const getTagData = async (url) => {
  await driver.get(url);
  const metas = await driver.executeScript(_scraper, 'meta');
  console.log(metas);
}
```